# How to create a signed url with Firebase/JWT?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-php-client

In the new version of Googles PHP-API-Cient the Google_Signer_P12 class was removed and now you should create signed urls via Firebase JWT (see https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/UPGRADING.md).

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me (I am  trying to generate signed urls for cloud storage downloads). My previous (working) code looked like this:

```
$signer = new \Google_Signer_P12( 'privatekey.p12' , 'notasecret' );
$stringToSign = 'GET' . "\n" . "\n" . "\n" . $expires . "\n". '/' . $bucketName . '/' . $fileName;
$signature = $signer->sign( utf8_encode( $stringToSign ) );
$finalSignature = \Google_Utils::urlSafeB64Encode( $signature );
```

I tried to replace this with:

```
$stringToSign = 'GET' . "\n" . "\n" . "\n" . $expires . "\n". '/' . $bucketName . '/' . $fileName;
$finalSignature = \JWT::encode(
   $stringToSign,
   'privateKey.p12'
);
```

but I receive a "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything in the docs on how to upgrade this part of the code.